# SQL - return all rows, however non-unique rows are merged into one (arithmetic performed)?

Tags: sql

I have a table where columns B, C, and D can be considered identifiers, and columns E - I are values. There will be some rows which are non-unique according to the identifiers i.e. the values for B, C and D match with those of some other row (possibly more than one row match).

I would like a query which returns all the rows as they are, with the exception of those non-unique rows. In these cases I would like to have only one row returned, with their values summed, with one exception, column E. This should be a weighted average with respect to column F i.e for every matching row the value returned should be the sum of E*F / sum of F

e.g

```
E, F  
7, 1  
9, 4  
E = (7*1 + 9*4)/(1+4) = 8.6
```

What query can I use to achieve to return the desired set of results?

All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
select B, C, D, sum(E*F) / sum(F), sum(F), sum(G), sum(H), sum(I)
from MyTable
group by B, C, D
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT B, C, D,
       SUM(E * F) / SUM(F) AS E_WEIGHTED,
       SUM(F) AS F_SUM,
       SUM(G) AS G_SUM,
       SUM(H) AS H_SUM,
       SUM(I) AS I_SUM
  FROM TableX
GROUP BY B, C, D
```

In general the GROUP BY clause is what will consolidate rows that share duplicate values (those columns you name in the GROUP BY clause).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT B,C,D,SUM(E*F)/SUM(F), SUM(F), SUM(G), SUM(H), SUM(I)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY B,C,D;
```